# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View] FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am trying to make a sample app using the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter but keep getting the error `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]` have tried everything but nothing seems to work

the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.visan.newappfireui, PID: 26711
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]
                      at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:172)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6078)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5248)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5158)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2061)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1445)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1408)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:580)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3379)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3188)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1595)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:323)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:919)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:710)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:642)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:905)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5582)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]
                      at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:528)
                      at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:492)
                      at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:169)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6078) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5248) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5158) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2061) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1445) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1408) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:580) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3379) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3188) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1595) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:323) 
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:919) 
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:710) 
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:642) 
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:905) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5582) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

my Main Activity, MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.visan.newappfireui;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DatabaseReference reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ailment");

        RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        adapter =new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ailment,DataHolder>(ailment.class,R.layout.recycler_row,DataHolder.class,reference){
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(DataHolder viewHolder, ailment model, int position) {
                viewHolder=new DataHolder(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(),getApplicationContext());
                viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
                viewHolder.setImg(model.getImg());
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        adapter.cleanup();
    }

    static class DataHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textView;
        private final Context context;

        public DataHolder(View v, Context context){
            super(v);
            imageView=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            textView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            this.context=context;
        }

        public void setName(String name){
            textView.setText(name);
        }

        public void setImg(String img){
            Picasso.with(context).load(img).centerCrop().into(imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

the Data object, ailment.java

```
package com.example.visan.newappfireui;

public class ailment {
    private String name;
    private String img;

     public ailment(){

     }

    public ailment(String name,String img){
        this.name=name;
        this.img=img;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getImg(){
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(String img){
        this.img=img;
    }
}
```

The two layout files,
This one is for the Main Activity, activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.visan.newappfireui.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is for the row of the recycler view, recycler_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/common_full_open_on_phone"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit: The Dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: what are your gradle dependencies, also do you by chance use Multidex

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Haven't  used MultiDex. btw I have added the dependencies

Comment: hmm what is `viewHolder=new DataHolder(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(),getApplicationContext());` and why?

Comment: Tried to initialize DataHolder constructor when nothing else seemed to work.

Answer (score 11):

Your `DataHolder`should be public like this

```
public static class DataHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{...}
```

Comment: também quero saber.

Comment: with static it's working fine. There is problem with firebase ui document https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#create-a-custom-viewholder