# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View] Firebase Recycler Adapter

Tags: android, firebase

Im getting error while running RecyclerView UI

```
 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<request_recycle, requestViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<request_recycle, requestViewHolder>(request_recycle.class, R.layout.request_trip_layout, requestViewHolder.class, query_car) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final requestViewHolder viewHolder, final request_recycle model, int position) {
};

}
```

Im getting this Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]
    at com.firebase.ui.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$a.b(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$p.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$p.a(Unknown Source)
```

Dependencies are :

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1' 
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1' 
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1' 
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0' 
 implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0' 
 implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
```

Comment: Which version of firebase you are using . Add the dependencies with question . Do mind using java naming conventions ...

Comment: This is my dependencies                                                              
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'

Comment: Try [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41927025/java-lang-nosuchmethodexception-init-class-android-view-view-firebaserecycl) . If problem is not solved add relevent code to question .

Comment: Sir My Dataholder       public static class requestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        View mview;
        MediaPlayer player;



        public requestViewHolder(final View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            mview=itemView;


        }

Comment: its already in static sir

Comment: @SIGPte have you tried my answer?

Comment: ya bro its working in emulator but in phone its not working same error appearing..

Answer (score 0):

Update both the `firebaseUI` dependencies to the following:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
```

So they become compatible with the firebase libraries that you are using, as it may be causing problems.

Then use the following code:

```
 FirebaseRecyclerOptions<request_recycle> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Chat>()
                    .setQuery(query_car, request_recycle.class)
                    .build();

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<request_recycle, requestViewHolder>(options) {
@Override
public ChatHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // Create a new instance of the ViewHolder, in this case we are using a custom
    // layout called R.layout.message for each item
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.request_trip_layout, parent, false);

    return new ChatHolder(view);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(ChatHolder holder, int position, Chat model) {
    // Bind the Chat object to the ChatHolder
    // ...
    }
 };
```

Do not forget to read the [docs](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/version-4.1.0/database/README.md#firebaseui-for-realtime-database), and check this:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/version-4.1.0/database/README.md#firebaserecycleradapter-lifecycle

You need to use `adapter.startListening();` so the data can appear in the recyclerview.